# Function that returns 1 if two arrays are completely different and 0 if there's a common element

Tags: c

I've tried this code but it doesn't seem to be working, how to break out of  the nested loop ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int meme(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int different;

    while (i <= strlen(s1) && different == 1) {
        while (j <= strlen(s2)) {
            if (s1[i] != s2[j]) {
                different = 1;
            } else {
                different = 0;
            }
            j = j + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return different;
}
```

Comment: did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: for a start u did not initialize different - so yr loop probably never runs

Comment: `different` is undefined. BTW it would be better to use `for` loop for your use case

Comment: There is a reason for compiler warnings. Any halfway recent compiler will warn. Don't ignore warnings. Before asking, you are expected to fix such warnings.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `different` the first time `while (i <= strlen(s1) && different == 1) {` is executed?

Comment: Let me translate your function for you. You initialize two iterators to the beginnings of `s1` and `s2`. Then you run all the way through s2,  setting `different` to 0 if the symbol at your current position in `s2` is the same as the beginning of `s1`, so at the end you'll know if `s1[0]==s2[strlen(s2)]`. Then you make one step in `s1`, realize that `j` has already reached the end of `s2`, increment `i` and start over. That is, if by accident `different` was set to 1 before you entered the loop. Otherwise you won't enter the loop at all. Is that your intended behavior?

Comment: Why iterate, `if (memcmp (arr1, arr2, size)) {... they are not equal ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with your code.
Why are you calling `strlen()` in `while()`? It will get executed every time till the loop doesn't exit and will cost on performance.

Also the variable `different` is not initialized with value `1`, so how can you be so sure about the initial value of that variable?

I have tried to simplify your function still, there is scope for optimization:

```
int meme(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int different;
    int str1_len = strlen(s1);
    int str2_len = strlen(s2);

    if(str1_len > str2_len)
        str1_len = str2_len;

        do{
            if(s1[i] == s2[i])
            {
                printf("Common\n");
                different = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                different = 1;
            }
            i++;
        }while(str1_len--); 
    return different;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to initialize `different` as it is undefined if not - this probably breaks your first while loop as `different` probably is a random number > 1.
2. `strlen` gives you the number of characters in the string excluding the null-character which terminates the string (see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm)). However, you do not only compare the characters of the two strings, but also the null-character, probably to implicitely check if the length of the strings is the same. While this should work, it is better to do this check explicitely by comparing the length of the strings first as it is less error-prone.
3. It isn't necessary to do a nested loop here if you compare the length of the strings first. Also, you now know the length of both strings, so this function can be change to use a for loop, which makes it even simpler.

A possible solution based on the points above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int meme(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int i = 0;
    int len_s1 = 0;
    int len_s2 = 0;
    int different = 0;

    len_s1 = strlen(s1);
    len_s2 = strlen(s2);
    if (len_s1 == len_s2) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < len_s1 ; i++) {
           if (s1[i] != s2[i]) {
              different = 1;
              break;
        }
    }
    else {
        different = 1;
    }

    return different;
}
```

One more thing - do yourself and everyone else a favor and intend your code as it is extremely hard to read otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not **optimized** and you are not using a good approach for doing the task. I have modified the code and it will do the job with **minimized complexity**.

Here I assume that both the **arrays are of same size** as your problem shows

```
bool meme(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(s1[i] != NULL && s2[i] != NULL)
    {
        if(s1[i] == s2[i])
            return false;
        i += 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When you call this function then declare a variable of type **bool** and store the **returned value** of this function in that variable.

For example :

```
bool check;
bool = meme(array 1 , array 2);
```

and then check if returned value is **true**, then both the arrays are totally different else not. You can do that by the below code :

```
if(check)
    printf("Arrays are different");
else
    printf("Arrays are not different");
```

You can also use int in place of bool if it suits you better but remember, whatever code you write, must be least complex. And think that if you are using int then also you are returning only **0 or 1**; but **int takes 2 bytes in 32-bit compiler and 4 bytes in 64-bit compiler**, but **bool takes only 1 byte and even 1 bit in some languages like pascal** (if I am not wrong).

And don't get confused with `return true;` and `return false;`. **True simply means 1 and false means 0**. And a **boolean** type variable can store only **binary number (1 or 0)**.